# Conjecture $_2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,\frac13\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac4{\sqrt{2-\sqrt[3]4}}+\sqrt[3]{4}+4}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt[3]4}-2}}$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, closed-form, conjectures, hypergeometric-function

Using a numerical search on my computer I discovered the following inequality:
$$\left|\,{_2F_1}\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,\frac13\right)-\rho\,\right|<10^{-20000},\tag1$$
where $\rho$ is the positive root of the polynomial equation
$$12\,\rho^8-12\,\rho^4-8\,\rho^2-1=0,\tag2$$
that can be expressed in radicals:
$$\rho=\frac1{\sqrt{\sqrt{\frac4{\sqrt{2-\sqrt[3]{4\vphantom{\large1}}}}+\sqrt[3]{4}+4}-\sqrt{2-\sqrt[3]4}-2}}.\tag3$$
Based on this inequality I conjecture that the actual difference is the exact zero, i.e.
$$\color{#808080}{_2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,\frac13\right)=\rho}.\tag4$$
I looked up in [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html), but did not find a known special value with exactly these parameters. It also appears that CAS like *Maple* or *Mathematica* do not know this identity.

---

Could you please suggest any ideas how to prove the conjecture $(4)$?

---

*Update:* I can propose even more general conjecture:
$$\color{#808080}{27\,(x-1)^2\cdot{_2F_1}\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;\tfrac23;x\right)^8+18\,(x-1)\cdot{_2F_1}\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;\tfrac23;x\right)^4-8\cdot{_2F_1}\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;\tfrac23;x\right)^2=1}$$

Comment: Really spectacular!

Comment: I would like to check it in PARI, but I do not know how the 2F1-function can be calculated there. Any ideas ?

Comment: I am wondering how you ensured an error less than $10^{-20000}$(?!*>+/@)

Comment: @user17762 Strictly speaking, I did not prove this boundary rigorously. I evaluated the difference using _Mathematica_ with a precision higher than $10^{-20000}$ (it took quite long time) and the result was not distinguishable from 0. _Mathematica_ documentation claims the result of a numeric calculation always contains only provably correct digits.

Comment: This is really beautiful ! Congratulations.

Comment: Presumably it can be proved through Glasser's approach to trinomials but I dare not to think about that.

Answer (score 56):

Let's start with this [Pfaff transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Fractional_linear_transformations) for $\,a=\frac 14,b=\frac34,c=\frac23$ :
$$\tag{1}_2F_1\left(a,b\;;c\;;z\right)=(1-z)^{-a}\;_2F_1\left(a,c-b\;;c\;;\frac z{z-1}\right)$$

The 'Darboux evaluation' $(42)$ of Vidunas' ["Transformations of algebraic Gauss hypergeometric functions"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4808v1) is :
$$\tag{2}_2F_1\left(\frac14,-\frac 1{12};\,\frac23;\,\frac {x(x+4)^3}{4(2x-1)^3}\right)=(1-2x)^{-1/4}$$

Solving $\,\displaystyle\frac {x(x+4)^3}{4(2x-1)^3}=\frac z{z-1}\,$ gives :
$$\tag{3}z=\frac{x(x+4)^3}{(x^2-10x-2)^2} $$
that we will use as :
$$\tag{4}z-1=\frac {4(2x-1)^3}{(x^2-10x-2)^2}$$

while $(1)$ and $(2)$ return :
$$_2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,z\right)=\left[(z-1)(2x-1)\right]^{-1/4}$$

so that :

$$_2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,z\right)=\left[\frac{4\,(2x-1)^4}{(x^2-10x-2)^2}\right]^{-1/4}$$
and (up to a minus sign) :
$$\tag{5}_2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,z\right)^2=-\frac{x^2-10x-2}{2\,(2x-1)^2}$$
and indeed the substitution of $(z-1)$ and $_2F_1()^2$ with $(4)$ and $(5)$ in your formula gives :
$$27\,(z-1)^2\cdot{_2F_1}\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;\tfrac23;z\right)^8+18\,(z-1)\cdot{_2F_1}\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;\tfrac23;z\right)^4-8\cdot{_2F_1}\left(\tfrac14,\tfrac34;\tfrac23;z\right)^2=1$$

Many other formulae of this kind may be deduced using Vidunas' paper.

Comment: I was about to bet that I should find you here ! Cheers.

Comment: Yes @Claude I am fond of special functions ! Cheers,

Comment: Dear Raymond - Outstanding. Beautifully resolves the "Update" conjecture. I was wondering if it also addresses the initial conjecture(4)? I.e., does the update come out of (4), or are they distinct? Thanks and best regards,

Comment: Thanks @96Tears! It doesn't give the explicit formula for $\rho$ (i.e. the initial $(3)$) but it provides the equation $(2)$ which is merely the specific case $z=\dfrac 13$ of the update formula (if you remember that $\displaystyle _2F_1\left(\frac14,\frac34;\,\frac23;\,\frac13\right)=\rho$). Cheers,

Answer (score 21):

The January issue of the [*Notices*](http://www.ams.org/notices/201401/index.html) has an article by Frits Beukers.  There is a criterion to decide whether certain hypergeometric functions are algebraic.  Checking these numbers in Theorem 2 of that article, we find that
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{2}{3};z\right)
$$
is an algebraic function of $z$.$^*$ He also mentions [H. A. Schwarz's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz's_list) of 1873; I did not check, but this is probably in it.

$^*$ Of course Raymond found (much more than) that in his solution.