# Is there a commonly accepted notation for algebraic numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, notation

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588680/112355) I needed a way to denote an algebraic number using a polynomial equation it satisfies and its isolating polynomial. Because I am not aware of any commonly accepted notation for this, I resorted to an explanation in English.

But I recall that I saw somewhere a notation like this:
$$\rho=\left[12\,x^8-12\,x^4-8\,x^2-1\right]_{1<x<2}$$

Is it commonly accepted and understandable? If not, can you suggest another good notation for that?

Comment: _MathWorld_ sometimes uses a similar notation (see below the formula $(19)$ at the bottom of [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html)), but with a root index rather than an isolating interval in the subscript. I do not think it is very common though.

Comment: I think that notation is fine, in fact it looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 4):

I have not seen the notation you have used. The easiest way is to write it out explicitly, i.e., $\rho$ is such that $\rho \in (1,2)$ and is a root of $f(x) = 12x^8 - 12 x^4 - 8x^2 - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [definite description quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#Mathematical_logic). As in:

$$\mathop{\iota}_{x:(1,2)}(0=12x^8−12x^4−8x^2−1)$$

But, I prefer your notation.